# Animate a view's alpha from 0 to 0.5

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, animation, nsview, alpha

I create an NSView which acts as an overlay view. I'd like to animate its alpha value from 0 to 0.5 after adding it as a subview of another view. I'm doing the following but I never see view's alpha animate to 0.5. I know the view has been added correctly because I see it if I set it's backgroundcolor to have full alpha. Am I missing something simple here?

```
self.overlayView = [[MyOverlayView alloc] initWithFrame:frameRect];
self.overlayView.layer.backgroundColor = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(0., 0., 0., 0.0);
[self.window.contentView addSubview:self.overlayView];

__typeof__(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
[NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context) {
     context.duration = 1;
     weakSelf.overlayView.animator.alphaValue = 0;
}
     completionHandler:^{
         weakSelf.overlayView.alphaValue = 0.5;
}];
```

I've also tried something like this:

```
[[self.overlayView animator] setAlphaValue:1.0];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't see a new subview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203988/cant-see-a-new-subview)

Comment: This isn't a dupe of that question. I can see the new subview... it just isn't animating the way I expect it to.

Comment: just replace with this line

[self.window.contentView addSubview:self.overlayView];

with this

[self.window.contentView.animator addSubview:self.overlayView];

animations will work properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set *wantsLayer* to YES.  The background color should also have an alpha of 1.0 not 0.0.

```
self.overlayView = [[MyOverlayView alloc] initWithFrame:frameRect];
self.overlayView.wantsLayer=YES;
self.overlayView.layer.backgroundColor = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(0., 0., 0., 1.0);
[self.window.contentView addSubview:self.overlayView];

__typeof__(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
[NSAnimationContext runAnimationGroup:^(NSAnimationContext *context) {
     context.duration = 1;
     weakSelf.overlayView.animator.alphaValue = 0;
}
     completionHandler:^{
         weakSelf.overlayView.alphaValue = 0.5;
}];
```

Comment: I think just the background color change is sufficient. Views don't need to be layer back to have a non-opaque `alphaValue` nor to animate it.

Comment: They need it if you set the background color of a layer which is what he is doing.  I tested the answer before posting it.

Answer (score 0):

just replace with this line

[self.window.contentView addSubview:self.overlayView];

with this

[self.window.contentView.animator addSubview:self.overlayView];

animations will work properly

Answer (score 0):

You need `wantsLayer` on the view you are going to animate, and also `animator` proxy object

```
let textField = NSTextField()
textField.wantsLayer = true

NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ context in
  context.duration = 1.0

  textField.stringValue = "\(emoji.visual) copied to clipboard"
  textField.animator().alphaValue = 1.0
}, completionHandler: {
   self.textField.alphaValue = 0.0
})
```